# formating and referencing minted section?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings, minted

I am currently trying to add a caption, center and reference a minted text, but seem to be unable to do so..

This is what i've tried so far...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

D is the number of deletion. A deletion is when a
word in the reference sentenced is not occuring in 
the hypothesised sentence as seen in example 
\ref{verb:deletion}\\


\begin{centering}
    \begin{listing}[H]
        \begin{minted}{bash}
           referenced: Today is monday. 
            hypothesised: Today monday.
        \end{minted}
    \caption{Example of the deletion metric of the WER, in which a word is deleted in the hypothesized compared to the referenced. }
    \label{verb:deletion}
    \end{listing}
\end{centering}

\end{document}
```

which gives me this

[image]

My problem is that it does not center, and could the listing in the caption be changed to something else? like example?... or are there any natural way to caption a minted box?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\listingscaption}{Example}` for the listing caption, easily to be found in the `minted` documentation

Comment: What do you mean by "section"?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: I think section means the `listing` float 'box', but it's a guess only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can change the caption name of the `listings` environment by redefining `\listingscaption` to whatever you want.
- The `minted` environment always takes up the whole available text width. You can see that when drawing a box around it (by adding the `frame=single` option to the minted environment). So it *is* properly centered, but because it takes up the whole text width, you don't see it.

  I don't know a way to make a `minted` environment dynamically *narrower*, but as a workaround, you could try to add margins on the left and the right of the `minted` environment (by adding the options `xleftmargin=...`, `xrightmargin=...`).
- In any case, this is the natural way to caption a `minted` environment.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\renewcommand{\listingscaption}{Example}

\begin{document}

D is the number of deletion. A deletion is when a word in the reference sentenced is not occuring in the hypothesised sentence as seen in example \ref{verb:deletion}.

\begin{listing}[H]\centering
    \begin{minted}[autogobble,xleftmargin=0.2\textwidth,xrightmargin=0.2\textwidth,frame=single]{bash}
        referenced: Today is monday. 
        hypothesised: Today monday.
    \end{minted}
    \caption{Example of the deletion metric of the WER, in which a word is deleted in the hypothesized compared to the referenced. }
    \label{verb:deletion}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some more notes:

- `autogobble` dynamically removes the common leading whitespace of every line.
- I use `frame=single` just for illustration here - you can easily remove it.
- The `centering` should not be around the floating environment `listing`, but inside it (although it has no effect in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the example..  I guess I will end up using your example, it does look neater than what i had before.